# Java FTPClient does not transfer the whole file

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client

I wrote a java class for downloading files from FTP server. Everything seem fine, but when I check the size of the files they are a bit smaller than original files.

Any idea why this happens?

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Downloader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String server = "ftp.example.gov";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "anonymous";
        String pass = "anonymous";
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

        try {
            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            ftpClient.cwd("dir1/dir2/gz");

            FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();

            for (FTPFile file : files) {
                String downloadFile = "/home/andrej/Documents/" + file.getName();
                OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile));
                boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(file.getName(), output);
                output.close();
                if (success) {
                    System.out.println(file.getName());
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How much smaller ? Can you include both file size ?

Comment: Size of original file (gzip) is 20 MB while the size of downloaded file is 16 MB.

Comment: Well, it probably doesn't have 4MB of carriage returns...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to download it in Binary mode, your difference might be due to the differences in carriage returns between the two servers. If your server is Windows, you will have CRLF, while Linux will only have New Line. The FTP in ASCII mode will do that conversion automatically for you.

When you compare both file, are they identical textwise? If so, I don't think you have to worry about it.

Comment: The `ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);` line solves the problem. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

Try output.flush() before output.close() to write the last buffered bytes to the file. Works for me! FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE didn't.